# Why does code blocks provide different answer for ++ operator when the variable are given data by normal assigh operator and scan option

Tags: c

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   int main()
   {

     int a=5,b;
     b=a++ + ++a ;
     printf("%d",b);
     return 0;
   }
```

//now give a =5 when you scan for a instead of assigining a=5.

Comment: `b=a++ + ++a ;`...perfect example of well-defined `undefined behaviour`.

Comment: I haven't got your answer can you tell me the reason for my question. just check the above code in codeblocks  you will get different answer .when a is assigned a value and when a get the same value using scanf

Comment: there is no logic that can define something called undefined behavior.

Comment: But I haven't got my answer . How can a same compiler can give two different answer when you are performing same task with same data.